# postdeploy schema changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, azure

In my sql project I have such scripts. This files has `build action = Build`.
It means that this sql code  will place in `model` file (sql server dac Package file).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class] (
        [Id]   SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
        [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    );
```

I want to make `build action = None` and place this code to post deploy file of dacpac.

But when I deploy this dacpac to db the second time I will get an error.

> "There is already an object named 'Class' in the database"

When this code is placed in model dacpac file I don't get this error.

**How I can push changes of schema to db via postdeploy file?**

**Should I use manual migration scripts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name='Class'
AND type='U'
)
Begin

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class] (
        [Id]   SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
        [Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    );
END
```